# Can gnuplot fetch plot data from remote locations (e.g. ftp servers)?

Tags: plot, ftp, gnuplot, remote-access

Plotting a datafile with gnuplot works like

```
plot 'filename' using 1:2
```

Is it possible that `'filename'` points to a remote location, e.g. `http://example.com/data.txt` or `ftp://ftp.example.com/data.txt`?

If so, does it work on Linux and Windows alike or are platform specific commands needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot directly open a file from a remote location via HTTP or FTP. You'll need to use a system-dependent command line program to fetch a data file on-the-fly, like the `GET` program. This is also used in the [linkedaxes demo](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_5.0/linkedaxes.html).

So in general, you'll have a command like

```
plot '< GET http://example.com/data.txt' using 1:2
```