# gnuplot: data from url

Tags: gnuplot

What is the best way to plot data from an url?

Currently, I have

```
pl "<wget -q -O - http://skuld.bmsc.washington.edu/scatter/data/Ta.dat" us 1:2
```

The option `-q` (quiet) suppresses download information and `-O -` redirects to stdout.

This relies on `wget` on Linux.

But I think, I have seen somewhere an even easier way.

Comment: If it works what do you want to simplify here? shorten the URL? I would be interested on how it would work under Windows.

Comment: The options are a bit hard to remember. I found again the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593603/can-gnuplot-fetch-plot-data-from-remote-locations-e-g-ftp-servers and http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_5.2/linkedaxes.html. There just `< GET` is used, but this command is not on my machine. I use now an updated link (http://skuld.bmsc.washington.edu/scatter/data/Ta.dat vs. old http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/scatter/data/Ta.dat).

Comment: Well, if you have `GET` _program_ installed, that is just a program and is part of `perl-libwww` package on my system, then you can use it. But if you don't, then you can't. So... ? `-q -O -` is not that much to remember. You minght find `curl` easier, but that is making your question opinion based. `What is the best way to plot data from an url?` "The best way" in what way? How do you measure what is "best"?

Comment: True. But it is good to collect the possibilities, since they seem to be platform dependent.