# Is there a Linux command line utility for getting random data to work with from the web?

Tags: linux, file, curl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a Linux newbie and I often find myself working with a bunch of random data.
For example: I would like to work on a sample text file to try out some regular expressions or read some data into gnuplot from some sample data in a csv file or something.

I normally do this by copying and pasting passages from the internet but I was wondering if there exists some combination of commands that would allow me to do this without having to leave the terminal. I was thinking about using something like the `curl` command but I dont exactly know how it works...

To my knowledge there are websites that host content. I would simply like to access them and store them in my computer.

In conclusion and as a concrete example, how would i copy and paste a random passage off the internet from a website and store it in a file in my system using only the command line? Maybe you can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Once you have selected and Ctrl-C'd your data in your browser, try `cat /dev/clipboard > /path/to/myTestData`. Good luck.

Comment: `curl` indeed can fetch the content of a webpage, and it can also save it to a file. Look for the `--output` option and examples in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).

Comment: ```wget -o- url``` shows content in console and ```wget -o filename url``` saves it to filename. In linux it is normal to use text tools instead of clipboarding. These gizmos have names like: echo cat grep sed awk cut . ..

Comment: See also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62300543/gnuplot-data-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect the output of a [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) command into a file e.g.

```
curl https://run.mocky.io/v3/5f03b1ef-783f-439d-b8c5-bc5ad906cb14 > data-output
```

Note that I've mocked data in [Mocky](https://designer.mocky.io/) which is a nice website for quickly mocking an API.

Comment: @MarkSetchell doh, agree! Changed,

Answer (score 1):

I normally use *"Project Gutenberg"* which has 60,000+ books freely downloadable [online](https://www.gutenberg.org).

So, if I want the full text of *"Peter Pan and Wendy"* by J.M. Barrie, I'd do:

```
curl "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/16/16-0.txt" > PeterPan.txt
```

If you look at the [page](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/16) for that book, you can see how to get it as HTML, plain text, ePUB or UTF-8.